# not able to access xml file from webserver

Tags: apache-2.2, http, httpd.conf

when i am trying  to aceess my html file of xml file after putting it in `var/www/html` i am not be able to access it from a browser.

for example ,

i have stored crossdomain.xml file in `var/www/html` folder after that i hit following url

`www.mydomain.com/crossdomain.xml` i am getting

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to mydomain.com
```

i dont know what is the issue here , can anyone please tell me

i restarted my server using `apachectl restart` after updating my `httpd.conf` file by adding `AddType` for `xml` but error remains same

Comment: I think it is not a file type problem, but seems that your server cannot be reached with its domain name. Did you try with ip address instead ?

Comment: Check your Apache logs, in /var/log/httpd or /var/log/apache2.  Did the request even arrive at your server (acces.log)?  Did it cause an error (error.log)?

Comment: there is nothing in error.log or access.log , wht should i do now

Answer (score 0):

Since you say that there's nothing in access.log, the request isn't arriving at your server.  So, you need to fix the DNS for your domain, to point to your server.  You can start by running

```
host www.mydomain.com
```

If the result doesn't show the IP address of your server, then you need to work through the domain registrar to fix that.